# how to create TEMP file to save int value when using timer

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

like the topic claims i need to save a value upon each time program timer executes.

here is the code and my program.

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("counter.txt"))
{
    String line;


    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Double coilVerdi = Convert.ToInt32(line);
        Int32 breddePlate = Convert.ToInt32(PlateBredde.Text);


        Double plateVekt = (breddePlate * 0.0016);
        Double svar = plateVekt += coilVerdi;
        coil.Text = svar.ToString();
        coil.Refresh();
    }


    r.Close();
}

Double t = Convert.ToDouble(coil.Text);
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("counter.txt"))
{
    writer.Write(t);
    writer.Close();

}
```

when new value is added to the program this code will be executed. what it does is to calculate a int value.
but every time i run code, all values are lost.i therefore save the values to file..and when timer runs next time it grabs value off file and add the new value to old value, after some time i get the correct countervalue.

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: the first time my code runs it makes a vale, lets say 1, then the value is saved to file..next time i want to use that value, open file,fetch value,and add 1 to the value in file.makes it 2, then save value 2 to file, and add 1 to it..etc etc. but i cant get it working :(

Answer (score 3):

you can declare an integer value in your project's settings:

[image]

and than use it in your code:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.Default.Counter = 123;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value as binary data, that way you will not have to convert it to text and back.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp;
using System.IO;



 class Program
 {
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
    AddCounter(5);
    Console.WriteLine(GetCounter());
    AddCounter(3);
    Console.WriteLine(GetCounter());
    AddCounter(7);
    Console.WriteLine(GetCounter());
  }


static void AddCounter(int nCounter)
{
    SetCounter(GetCounter() + nCounter);
}


static void SetCounter(int nValue)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("counter.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            bw.Write(nValue);
        }
    }
}

static int GetCounter()
{
    int nRes = 0;
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("counter.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
        {
            if (br.PeekChar() != -1)
            {
                nRes = br.ReadInt32();
            }
        }
    }
    return nRes;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> "but every time i run code, all values are lost."

If you wish to retain your original values, you need to append the existing file:

```
  using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("counter.txt", true)) {
    writer.Write(t);
    writer.Close();
  }
```

Comment: Your code has `StreamWriter("counter.txt")`. You should try `StreamWriter("counter.txt", true)`. [Note the `true` overload on the end]